# PHP script to json_encode returns escaped forward slash

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP script that scrapes a database daily and pushes a json feed to a downstream process. We have some logic in the middle that we are trying to create a list called types.

```
$sql =
    "SELECT
    id AS slug,
    name,
    CONCAT('[',
        IF (closed = 0, 'O', 'C'),
        IF (mandatory = 1, ', M', ''),
        IF (weekend = 1, ', W', ''),
        ']'
    ) AS types
    FROM meetings as meetings";
```

The issue we are having is the downstream process expects the list types to have each value in quotes:

```
"types": [
    "O",
    "M",
    "W"],
```

However, when we escape the quotes, they end up in the json feed:
`IF (closed = 0, '/"O/"', '/"C/"')`

The question is whether this is the correct approach and is the output of how json_encode is intended to operate.

We return the query row by row into a php array (while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) $return[] = $row;) and then dump to json.

```
//function to output json
function output($array) {
    $return = json_encode($array);
    if (json_last_error()) error(json_last_error_msg());
    die($return);
}
```

I have played around with some of the json_encode constants: JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES and such as well as omitting the escape slash. My expectation is that it shouldn't be this difficult or I am missing something incredibly simple.

Expected output:

```
"types": [
    "O",
    "M",
    "W"],
```

Comment: Don't create the array in SQL. Create it in PHP and then call `json_encode()` .

Comment: Why are you putting forward slashes in the JSON in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Don't create the JSON by concatenating strings. You're going to double-encode it when you put it in the array and then call `json_encode()`. Just return the data, put it into the array, and then encode that.

```
$sql =
    "SELECT
    id AS slug,
    name,
    closed, mandatory, weekend
    FROM meetings as meetings";
//...
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $return_row = [
        'slug' => $row['slug'],
        'name' => $row['name'],
        'types' => [$row['closed'] == 0 ? 'O' : 'C']
    ];
    if ($row['mandatory'] == 1) {
        $return_row['types'][] = 'M';
    }
    if ($row['weekend'] == 1) {
        $return_row['types'][] = 'W';
    }
    $return[] = $return_row;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense. We appreciate the help!